# WebUSB transferout to customer display nothing happens

Tags: javascript, pos, webusb

I'm developing a web application in which I have to display prices on a customer display, for tests purposes I bought a TYSSO VFD-860 (With the hope to make a general solution that works on every customer display), and I'm trying to communicate with it using WebUSB API, I made that previously for thermal printer and it worked, so I thought it was a good idea to write use the same code for the display, but I'm having nothing, no errors and nothing displayed on the screen.

My code:

```
function selectEndpoint(direction, device) {
  const endpoint = device.configuration
    .interfaces[0]
    .alternate
    .endpoints.find(ep => ep.direction == direction);

  if (endpoint == null)
    throw new Error(`Endpoint ${direction} not found in device interface.`);
  return endpoint;
}

document.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [] })
  await device.open()
  console.log(device)
  const { interfaceNumber } = device.configuration.interfaces[0];
  await device.claimInterface(interfaceNumber);
  const outpoint = selectEndpoint("out", device);
  const inpoint = selectEndpoint("in", device);
  const str = "Hello";
  const bytes = str.split("").map(char => char.charCodeAt(0));
  const data = new Uint8Array(bytes);
  device.transferOut(outpoint.endpointNumber, data);
  await device.close()
})
```

**Some other infos that may help**

device name in popup: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge controller

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the device will display anything if you just start writing bytes to it?

It shouldn't affect anything in this particular case but you should await the result of the transferOut() call so that the device isn't closed while the transfer is still pending.